# Do the nights 'draw in' or 'pull in'?

Tags: idioms

In Norfolk, in my youth, people would always talk about the nights ***pulling in*** in  the months running up to Christmas, when daylight would be reduced to approx. 7.5 hours a day. In the spring the nights would ***draw out***, till daylight at the solstice reached about 17.5 hours.

**So my recollection is that the nights *pulled in* and *drew out***.

This morning, following the clocks changing back to GMT for the winter, I have heard some people on TV talking about the nights ***drawing in***.

So do they ***draw in*** or ***pull in***?

Comment: It is an idiom that is unfamiliar to me.  In the US, days get shorter and longer.  (And, since the words mean essentially the same thing, this is more a question of what's idiomatic than what's "correct".)

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, my father was from Norfolk (Heathersett). I am trying but failing to remember if he used to talk about 'pulling the curtains' when my mother would say 'drawing the curtains'. WS2 - Which do you say?

Comment: Curious. I am from Yorkshire, and we would use 'drawing in' to mean that the night was coming, as in "better get home... the night's drawing in", in a way synonymous to 'night is falling'. But... 'the nights are pulling in' is used (albeit rarely in my experience, and normally by the old folk) to mean the nights are getting longer. I rationalised it as using a synonym to avoid confusion, but now you have made me reconsider!

Comment: In the South West of England, it's always "drawing in" in my experience. I only ever heard "pulling in" when I lived in Sheffield.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - In my experience it's more likely to be "drawing the curtains" than "pulling the curtains" in the US, though both are used.  And there's likely some difference based on the physical mechanism employed.

Comment: We used to say *draw the curtains*. But the nights definitely *pulled in*. Norfolk being an agricultural county - with much folklore about the weather etc - you can always rely on someone (now perhaps an older person) to remark sometime in early September that the *nights are pulling in*. Equally in April someone will invariably note *nights are drawing out, aren't they*. Interestingly no one seems to notice what's happening to the mornings!

Comment: @WS2, Apologies if this has now descended into chat--if relevant chat. I can definitely say that my old dad, Norfolk born and bred never uttered the words, 'the nights are pulling in' in my hearing--I would have noticed. Maybe it is more localised than we think? P.S. I don't think it is purely agricultural as the family had strong farming connections. I used to work on my uncle's farm during the summer as a youngster.

Comment: Anecdotally, where I grew up in Scotland, it was always "Aye, the nights are fair drawing in."

Answer (score 5):

Pulling and drawing are exact synonyms in this context.

> **draw** verb (PULL)
>
> C2 [T + adv/prep] to ​pull or ​direct something in a ​particular
>   ​direction:
>   She drew her ​coat ​tightly around her ​shoulders.
>   The ​crowd ​watched as the ​referee drew the ​player ​aside/to one ​side and ​spoke to him.
>   draw the curtains   › to ​pull ​curtains so that
>   they are either together or ​apart
>
> [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draw)

**Examples**

*Some people use 'pull the curtains' and others say 'draw the curtains'.*

*A horse can draw a cart or pull a cart.*

So it is simply a local difference but it means the same thing.

A check on [Google ngram: nights pull in,nights draw in,night pulls in,night draws in](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nights%20pull%20in%2Cnights%20draw%20in%2Cnight%20pulls%20in%2Cnight%20draws%20in&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnights%20draw%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnight%20draws%20in%3B%2Cc0) shows that, for most publications, nights draw rather than pull.

[image]

---

Detail

[image]

Comment: I think your chart is potentially misleading. Since we're discussing the relative prevalence of ***draw*** vs ***pull***, anyone who can't read the minuscule "Ngrams not found" label might assume the two are roughly comparable. But Google Books claims 2,080 results for [*the nights are drawing in*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+nights+are+drawing+in%22), as against just 5 instances of [*the nights are **pulling** in*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+nights+are+pulling+in%22). Idiomatically, the latter version isn't really in the running.

Comment: @FumbleFingers clicking on the image opens it in a new tab/page, so you can read the small print.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I've added a closeup. Note that I also gave a link to the original ngram.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, chasly: I know that. I couldn't actually read the label myself, but although I was *almost* 100% certain the ***pull*** versions would be far too rare to chart, I felt obliged to click thru the link to make sure anyway. That's why I posted my comment in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I posted the comment explaining how someone else, who might not know, could enlarge the image.